# How to find the optimal $\theta$ that minimizes $\left\| \frac{c\:e^{j\theta}- a^H x}{\|a\|_2^2}a \right\|_2^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, complex-numbers

I need to find an optimal $\theta$ that minimizes

$$\left\| \frac{c\:e^{j\theta}- a^H x}{\|a\|_2^2}a \right\|_2^2 \ ,$$
where $(\cdot)^H$ denotes complex conjugate transpose, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $a, x \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

---

I am told that the optimal $\theta$ is angle of $a^H x$ such that $e^{j\theta}= \frac{a^H x}{|a^H x|}$, but I don't how to prove it. Can anyone prove this?

Comment: What is the closest point on a circle of radius $c$ to $a^Hx$? Why are you taking the $2$-norm of a scalar?

Comment: Plugging in $e^{j \theta} = \frac{a^H x}{| a^H x|}$ into the expression yields $$\left\|\frac{a^H x a}{\|a\|_2^2} \left(\frac{c}{| a^H x|}- 1\right) \right\|^2$$ Now $\frac{a^H x a}{\|a\|_2^2}$ looks very familiar (Rayleigh quotient).

Comment: Let $\lambda = (ce^{j\theta}-a^Hx)\;$ 
and note that $$\eqalign{
\min\,\Bigg\|\frac{\lambda a}{\|a\|^2}\Bigg\|^2
 &= \min\,\frac{\|a\|^2}{\|a\|^2}\,|\lambda|^2 
 &= \min\,|\lambda|^2 \\
}$$
Then re-read @copper.hat 's comment.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik, thanks. I have also removed complex-analysis tag.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for the hint. So, the oral solution makes sense, but sorry if I am asked to derive the solution mathematically then I probably need to approach the way greg suggested.

Comment: @greg thank you. then I need to take the derivative with respect to $\theta$, then I need to set $\lambda$ to 0, which will be $e^{j\theta} = \frac{a^H x}{c}$. This doesn't look right, that is, instead of $c$ i need $|a^H x|$ ? Or am I still making stupid mistake

Comment: Recall that $e^{j\theta}$ has a modulus of ${\tt\large 1}$, so you cannot set it to some arbitrarily value. The **_best_** you can do is to have it point in the same direction as $a^Hx\;$ (in the complex plane).

Comment: @greg thank you. I think I get it.